# Send on behalf of feature of DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

We are working on integration of DocuSign Api with application.
How often 'Send On Behalf Of' feature of DocuSign is used by end user? Is it a common use case?

Answer (score 1):

It's quite common.  If you choose to you oAuth for authentication sobo becomes less important since you are essentially authenticating as the user in question. You can read more about it from the DocuSign docs but if you have any more questions feel free.

https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/sobo